How to configure yiisoft/yii-swagger package?
How Can I configure routing that package yiisoft/swagger is using? I installed all necessary packages, but still can't use routes like Route::...
Documentation of yiisoft/router https://github.com/yiisoft/router says that I have to do somenthing like:
// Define routes
$routes = [
    Route::get('/')
        ->action(static function (ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $next) use ($responseFactory) {
            $response = $responseFactory->createResponse();
            $response
                ->getBody()
                ->write('You are at homepage.');
            return $response;
        }),
    Route::get('/test/{id:\w+}')
        ->action(static function (CurrentRoute $currentRoute, RequestHandlerInterface $next) use ($responseFactory) {
            $id = $currentRoute->getArgument('id');
    
            $response = $responseFactory->createResponse();
            $response
                ->getBody()
                ->write('You are at test with argument ' . $id);
            return $response;
        })
];

// Add routes defined to route collector
$collector = $container->get(RouteCollectorInterface::class);
$collector->addGroup(Group::create(null)->routes($routes));

// Initialize URL matcher
/** @var UrlMatcherInterface $urlMatcher */
$urlMatcher = new UrlMatcher(new RouteCollection($collector));

// Do the match against $request which is PSR-7 ServerRequestInterface. 
$result = $urlMatcher->match($request);

if (!$result->isSuccess()) {
     // 404
}

// $result->arguments() contains arguments from the match.

// Run middleware assigned to a route found.
$response = $result->process($request, $notFoundHandler);

But where to put this configuration code? All of this in routes.php?
When I just add route configuration like:
Route::get('/health-check')->action([HealthCheckController::class, 'index']),

I receive exception `Exception (Invalid Configuration)
'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'URL rule class must implement UrlRuleInterface.

I have tried to put this config in routes.php file but without success.

What version of Yii framework are you using? You've added Yii 2 tag and the exception looks like it's from Yii 2. But the package yiisoft/yii-swagger looks like it's for Yii 3. Yii 3 and Yii 2 uses completely different routing you won't be able to use Yii 3 like routing in Yii 2. Or at least it's unnecessary complicated to get it working.

I'm using 2.0.49.3.
If this package is for Yii3, are You aware if there is any proper package for swagger for Yii2?
I checked version 1.22 of yii-swagger and it has also routing like that

Looks like there are some: https://packagist.org/search/?q=yii2%20swagger
But I didn't use any of them, so you will have to check them for yourself.
